# ¿Cómo cambiar la paleta de colores de Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4, scss

he tropezado con este problema y me urge encontrar la solución. El asunto en concreto es que tengo un Theme/Framework de WordPress que he hecho y lo he migrado a Bootstrap 4. He usado los archivos fuentes `*.scss` para generar el `style.css` y todo bien hasta ahí.

El problema surge cuando desde un Child Theme necesito cambiar el esquema de colores para adaptarlo al diseño del proyecto, pues me es muy complicado y la solución que he encontrado no sirve, pues no tiene una sola ventaja a su favor.

En el framework tengo un archivo `_style.scss` que contiene este código:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss";
@import "css/icomoon-variables.scss";
@import "css/icomoon.scss";
@import "css/theme.scss";
```

En el Child Theme incluyo el archivo `_style.scss` del Framework y he intentado cambiar los colores de la siguiente manera:

```
$red:                   #F44336;
$pink:                  #E91E63;
$purple:                #9C27B0;
$deep-purple:           #673AB7;
$indigo:                #3F51B5;
$blue:                  #2196F3;
...

$colors:(
    red: $red,
    pink: $pink,
    purple: $purple,
    deep-purple: $deep-purple,
    indigo: $indigo,
    blue: $blue,
    ...
);

$theme-colors: (
    primary: $orange,
    success: $teal,
    info: $deep-purple,
    warning: $deep-orange,
    danger: $red
);
```

pero no funciona, después de varias horas de intentar muchas combinaciones lo único que pude lograr (para cambiar el color de los `.alert`) fue re-escribir la función que genera el `.alert-#color`. Entonces no puedo re-escribir estas funciones para cada elemento de Bootstrap, ni puedo añadir los colores al archivo fuente `_variables.scss` porque cada proyecto lleva un esquema de colores diferente y a fin de cuentas no es lo correcto.

¿Hay alguna manera sencilla de añadir colores a la paleta de Bootstrap?

Gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 1):

Esto es un tanto complejo. El detalle es que para modificar los archivos `.scss` debes tener instalado el `SASS` y generar un nuevo `bootstrap.css`. Si tu modificas los archivos `.scss` sin el `SASS`, no se generará el nuevo archivo `css` y por tanto no tomará los archivos. Si, si estas trabajándolo con `SASS`, asegúrate de que está generando un nuevo `css`, ya que a veces ,por si solo, el `SASS` no lo genera. Para ello, deberás usar un monitor `SASS` como **Scout-App** que te permitirá generar el archivo y te ayudará a generar el nuevo archivo a medida que estés modificándolo con algún editor, como **Notepad++** o **Brackets**.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Estaría mejor que pudieras poner alguna referencia a un sitio que toque el tema de tu respuesta y te ayude a mejorarla o complementarla. Te recomiendo que leas este artículo [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).